# __uint128_t not working with Clang and libstdc++

Tags: c++, g++, clang++, libstdc++, int128

Consider the following small test program for type traits of the GNU-extensions for `__uint128_t`

```
#include <limits>
#include <type_traits>

using uint128_t = __uint128_t;

int main()
{
    static_assert(std::is_unsigned<uint128_t>{}, ""); 
    static_assert(std::is_integral<uint128_t>{}, "");
    static_assert(std::numeric_limits<uint128_t>::digits == 128, "");
}
```

This works for g++ and libstdc++ ([working example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/98f328cda9fa396e)) and for clang++ and libc++ ([working example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/22d19816625f7c17)), but not for the combination clang++ and libstdc++ ([failing example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a23b44df10ea3fad)).

Note that in all 3 cases I use the `-std=gnu++1z` flag.

**Question**: which combination of command-line parameters can successfully compile my test program for clang++ with libstdc++?

Comment: This isn't about standard C++, this is about GNUC++. GCC fails the static asserts in `-std=c++1z` mode as well. From the standard's perspective, the way GCC has defined this type means it's not an integer type, just a custom type that happens to work pretty much like an integer type, and in standard-conforming mode the type traits reflect that. (I'm not sure how clang/libc++ have defined it. It's possible that it qualifies as an integer type in their implementation.)

Comment: @hvd note that in all 3 examples, I use `-std=gnu++1z`, and only in the case clang + libstdc++ did it fail

Comment: I know, I commented in an attempt to clarify, not to dismiss your question. :)

Comment: For the `std::numeric_limits<uint128_t>` on Apple platforms, see [Apple Clang and numeric_limits<unsigned __int128>::max() is 0?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41666815/608639)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the non-standard `-std=gnu++*` modes, GCC predefines two macros that libstdc++ picks up to provide additional type traits:

```
$ g++ -std=gnu++1z -c -E -dM -xc++ /dev/null | grep INT_N
#define __GLIBCXX_BITSIZE_INT_N_0 128
#define __GLIBCXX_TYPE_INT_N_0 __int128
```

clang doesn't define these. Manually defining them, by passing `-D__GLIBCXX_TYPE_INT_N_0=__int128` and `-D__GLIBCXX_BITSIZE_INT_N_0=128` on the command line, makes your test case work with clang.

Adding these in clang itself is https://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=23156, which is marked as fixed, but I'm not sure in which version. I have 3.8.1 installed locally, where it does not work, but I haven't checked 3.9.0.