# Apple Clang and numeric_limits<unsigned __int128>::max() is 0?

Tags: c++, clang, numeric-limits

I'm trying to figure out the best way to work around an apparent bug where `numeric_limits<T>::max()` returns 0 rather than the maximum value.

First, the test program:

```cxx
$ cat test.cxx
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
#if (__SIZEOF_INT128__ >= 16)
    std::cout << "__int128 is available" << std::endl;
#else
    std::cout << "__int128 is not available" << std::endl;
#endif

    unsigned __int128 m = std::numeric_limits<unsigned __int128>::max();
    if (m == 0)
        std::cout << "numeric_limits<unsigned __int128>::max() is 0" << std::endl;
    else
        std::cout << "numeric_limits<unsigned __int128>::max() is not 0" << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The `__SIZEOF_INT128__ >= 16` test came from a discussion on the GCC mailing list at [128-bit integer - nonsensical documentation?](https://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc-help/2015-08/msg00185.html).

And the result:

```
$ c++ -Wall test.cxx -o test.exe
$ ./test.exe
__int128 is available
numeric_limits<unsigned __int128>::max() is 0
```

Apple has also abandoned the platform and tools, so a bug report won't get the problem fixed.

How can we work around the issue?

---

I'm not sure how to proceed. To fix the problem in the code, as opposed to the minimal example above, we *really* need to override the function in the `std` namespace. But [overriding a function in `std` is not allowed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1375018/overriding-std-functions).

Here's an example of why its a problem in the real code:

```cxx
template<class T1, class T2>
T1 Add(const T1& t1, const T2& t2)
{
    if (std::numeric_limits<T1>::max() - t2 > t1)
        throw std::runtime_error("overflow");

    return t1 + t2;
}
```

In the code above, we have to provide a full specialization for every combination of `T1 = __int128` and `T2` imaginable. Its not realistic.

---

The compiler version on the problematic machine:

```
$ c++ --version
Apple LLVM version 6.0 (clang-600.0.57) (based on LLVM 3.5svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0
Thread model: posix
```

However, jumping over to a non-Apple test machine produces expected results:

```
$ clang++-3.5 --version
Debian clang version 3.5.0-10 (tags/RELEASE_350/final) (based on LLVM 3.5.0)
Target: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix

$ clang++-3.5 -Wall test.cxx -o test.exe

$ ./test.exe
__int128 is available
numeric_limits<unsigned __int128>::max() is not 0
```

Comment: Try a newer clang. I cannot reproduce the issue with `Apple LLVM version 8.0.0 (clang-800.0.42.1)`. My guess is that `std::is_arithmetic<__int128>::value` is `false` in your older version of clang, because then you get the default implementation of [`__libcpp_numeric_limits`](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/libcxx/blob/master/include/limits) which yields zero for `min`/`max`/etc. Also, I think your overflow detection is UB if `t2` is negative (and the type is signed).

Comment: You are supposed to check `is_specialized` before using `numeric_limits`...

Comment: @Cornstalks - Thanks. The version of Apple Clang on OS X 10.9 with Xcode 6.0 is fixed. As far as I know, there are no other versions (and we don't depend on users installing them or building them from scratch). The `Add` example was meant to demonstrate the problem with full specializations, and not a robust add.

Comment: @Cronstalk - why does Apple's Clang fail to throw a *"not implemented"* or similar? What good does it do to silently produce bad results?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write `notstd::numeric_limits<T>:std::numeric_limits<T>`

Specialize if for `T` which have a bug, overloading `static max()` (and whatever else) with the right behaviour.

Use `notstd::numeric_limits` in `Add`.

Or use a newer compiler and/or standard library.